# Как отследить изменение состояния при переходе с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Есть две страницы Questions и Home. На странице Questions есть форма, которая отправляет данные на сервер. Также по submit мы переходим со страницы Questions на страницу Home. Все я делаю с использованием vuex.

```
function setAnswers(answers) {
    store.dispatch('setAnswers', answers);
    router.push({ name: 'Home' });
}
```

Далее работает данный action

```
async setAnswers({ dispatch, commit }, answers) {
    await Account.setAnswers(answers);
    dispatch('getPastPeriods');
    dispatch('getPredictablePeriods');
}
```

Который соответственно вызывает два других actions.

```
getPast({ commit }) {
    return Account.getPast(response => {
        return commit('SET_PAST', response.data);
    });
},
getNext({ commit }) {
    return Account.getNext(response => {
        return commit('SET_NEXT', response.data);
    });
},
```

Соответственно срабатывают следующие мутации

```
SET_ANSWERS(state, answers) {
    state.answers = answers;
},
SET_PAST(state, past) {
    state.past = past;
    сonsole.log('past',past);
},
SET_PREDICTABLE_PERIODS(state, next) {
    state.next = next;
    сonsole.log('next',next);
},
```

При этом на странице Home *past* и *next* отслеживаются через computed и передаются другому компоненту.

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full h-full">
        <Component
            :past="past"
            :next="next"
        />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Component from '@/components/template/Component.vue';
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const store = useStore();

const past = computed(() => store.state.past);
const next = computed(() => store.state.next);
</script>
```

В консоли я вижу, что эти значения устанавливаются, но в Home данные не обновляются. Каким образом можно решить данный случай и может я просто что-то не так выполняю. Буду рада любой помощи)

Comment: Данные, приходят куда позже чем открытие вашей страницы — отсюда такой эффект, подумайте над тем так ли важно брать данные с сервера когда они есть у Вас локально, разумеется нужно убеждаться что на сервере они сохранились, но это уже детали.

Comment: Наиболее правильно было бы сделать отображение лоадера на момент до того как произойдет SET_*, а после — данные будут уже синхронизированны

Comment: @DaniilLoban, благодарю за информацию, также задумывалась, стоит ли ждать данные с сервера, может просто обработать их и сразу установить в переменную. Но подумала, может есть какая-то определенная практика для подобных случаев и кто-нибудь подскажет)

Comment: Общий совет — `один источник истины`, но не уверен что в данном случае он поможет. На всякий случай опишите какую задачу Вы решаете в обобщенном смысле, чтобы было понятно могу ли я что-то посоветовать в конкретно Вашем случае, можно ли сразу все обработать.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в общем суть в том, что мне нужно передать данные из формы. На основе этих данных рассчитывается другая информация и записывается в другую таблицу. Эти данные нужно сразу получить и установить в состояние. И все это за один  dispatch. Я рассматривала решение с лоадером, но, к сожалению, его значение завязано на  get, post и я не смогла перенастроить это все - слишком много придется переделывать. Поэтому я просто осуществила обработку данных формы сразу в vue.

Comment: Если расчет можно сделать на клиентской части ( в браузере) как правило так нужно делать, а если данные из  таблиц должны хранится в БД на сервере, то нужно убедиться через какое-то время когда ответ с сервера придет что в ответе не было ошибки, этот запрос на сохранение можно снова повторить в фоне, но желательно еще отслеживать статус онлайн, Facebook и Stackoverflow  именно так себя    и ведут, да и многие другие сайты

Comment: @DaniilLoban, большое спасибо за пояснение!)